# Retrieving a MenuItem

Tags: android, android-studio, menuitem

My menu item works as a toggle button, it switches from icon "a" and "b". When the orientation of the app changes i save the state inside the bundle and retrieve it during next onCreate. But i need to put the icon in its correct state:

```
if(muted){
            item.setChecked(true);
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.muted);
        }
        else{
            item.setChecked(false);
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.unmuted);
        }
```

but how do i get the item reference?

Comment: Why dont you just call item.setChecked() when needed and handle the rest yourself? I am not sure if I get your problem. What kind of Item is it? MenuItem?

Comment: It is a menu item, and i cant just call item.setChecked() for the very same reason, i dont know how to retrieve the MenuItem using the id.

Comment: When you inflate the menu (or create it somehow else) hold the reference, then call MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.something), store the reference in the activity and call the setChecked when needed.

Comment: But i'm using the action bar, so i never actually inflate it

Comment: Can you provide the code, how you use the actionBar ?

Comment: well i'm just using it the standard way (or so i believe)
on menu/my.xml i have the code:
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_mute"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/unmuted"
        android:title="@string/action_mute"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>

pretty much what i want is the current icon to persist after a rotation

Comment: Can you tell me your purpose of retrieving menu item? I might be able to give you some alternatives.

Comment: My menu item works as a toggle button, it switches from icon "a" and "b". When the orientation of the app changes i save the state inside the bundle and retrieve it during next onCreate. But i need to put the icon in its correct state.

Comment: how do you use/include this menu? I think we're close

Comment: i don't think i fully understand you. I didn't add any code to include the action bar, it is already there i just edited the it's xml and added my item then on the java there's already a method: "@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)" wich is where i handle the item clicks but i never call the method myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_item_id);
if(muted){
    item.setChecked(true);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.muted);
}
else{
    item.setChecked(false);
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.unmuted);
}
```

And if you need to update state of item just call invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: i had actually tried that already as @Michael suggested in the comments, but it doesnt always work and even when it does it makes me have to click 2 times on the item for it to change. Thats why i'm trying to do it during activity onCreate

Comment: It works now, i had to use the reference inside the onCreateOptionsMenu like @Michael and you said the reason it didn't always worked was because i bundled some other validations when i was checking for the savedInstanceState not to be null.